# How to get whole array from completion block after loading data

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a trouble with returning array of data to completion block

have a look:

I have function that getting data from API:

```
public func getCityWeather(completion: @escaping (Weather) -> ()){
    
        for i in citiesGeo {
            let urlString = "https://api.weather.yandex.ru/v2/forecast?lat=\(i.latitude)&lon=\(i.longitude)"
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {continue}
        
            self.loadManager.getWeather(url: url) { (weather) in
            completion(weather)
        }
    }
}
```

And get it here:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        weatherLoader.getCityWeather { (weather) in
            print(weather)
        }
    }
}
```

And it's ok, BUT how can I get all the cities weather into array and after that send it into completion block so I'll can get it from ViewDidLoad function.

Hope, you will help

Comment: You could use a [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).

Comment: @Don , thanks for answer, I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Don for help.
I answer to my question.
Using DispatchGroup work perfectly. Below I'll show the code

```
  public func getCityWeather(completion: @escaping ([Weather]) -> ()){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup() //create dispatch group
        for i in self.citiesGeo {
            downloadGroup.enter() //indicate that we enter
            let urlString = "https://api.weather.yandex.ru/v2/forecast?lat=\(i.latitude)&lon=\(i.longitude)"
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {continue}
            
            self.loadManager.getWeather(url: url) { (weather) in
                self.citiesWeather.append(weather)
                downloadGroup.leave() //indicate that task completed
            }
        }
        downloadGroup.wait() //wait until all the "enter" find their "leave"
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(self.citiesWeather) //send array to completion block
         }
      
    }
}
```